# Compute Number of Bits Used Without Building Huffman Tree

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, entropy

Say, I have a list of integers `x = [102, 102, 102, 1, 0, -1, -2000, -3, 3, 102, 1, 0, -1, -1, -2000, -2000, -2000, -2000, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 3]` and the frequencies for each number is:

```
Integer  Count
    102      4
      3      2
      1      3
      0      4
     -1      5
     -3      1
  -2000      5
```

If I generate a Huffman tree and then encode this sequence, I find that the total number of bits necessary for encoding this list is 65 bits. In theory, the order of the integers shouldn't matter (i.e., I can shuffle this list of integers) as it should still produce the same number of bits (65).

Considering that I only want to compute the number of bits and I don't care about the actual encoding or the tree, is there a faster/better way to compute  the number of bits used (i.e., 65) without having to explicitly construct the Huffman tree? Perhaps, it may be possible to generate the bit count based on the frequency count alone?

Comment: Caveat: You are encoding a deterministic sequence, doing an estimation of the "probabilities". In that case, you'll need to include in the coded sequence the encoding tree (symbols and estimated probabilities). Then, you'd need more than 65 bits.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for the binary entropy -- the average number of bits required to encode your symbols. To get that, you divide the entropy in nats by log(2.0). I get an answer of 2.66937 bits per symbol. Multiply that by 24 symbols, and you get an answer of 64.0649 bits. Take the ceiling of that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    vector<long signed int> input = {102, 102, 102, 1, 0, -1, -2000, -3, 3, 102, 1, 0, -1, -1, -2000, -2000, -2000, -2000, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 3};
    
    size_t length = input.size();

    double entropy = 0.0;

    if (length > 0)
    {
        map<long signed int, size_t> input_map;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
            input_map[input[i]]++;

        for (map<long signed int, size_t>::const_iterator ci = input_map.begin(); ci != input_map.end(); ci++)
        {
            double probability = ci->second / static_cast<double>(length);

            cout << "Number: \'" << ci->first << "\', Count: " << ci->second << ", Probability: " << probability << endl;

            entropy += probability * log(probability);
        }

        entropy = -entropy;
    }

    cout << "Entropy: " << entropy/log(2.0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is awfully close but I tried other input lists and the number of bits seem approximate (even with rounding up) and gets worse as the length of the list gets longer.

Comment: My apologies. It likely only works where the probabilities are all equal. Then the binary entropy equals log(n) / log(2.0), where n is the number of distinct symbols.

Comment: This should give you an upper bound. Do you see where I’m coming from?

Comment: The other measure (64.1) would be the lower bound.

Comment: Apropos of this proposal - let $n_i$ be the number of times symbol $i$ appears in the list, and $L_i$ the length of the Huffman encoding, and $n = \sum n_i$.  Using the source coding theorem and the optimality of the Huffman code gives the bounds $$ nH(\{n_i/n\}) \le \sum n_iL_i \le nH(\{n_i/n\}) + n.$$ I believe that this is tight, and the gap really can be linear in $n$ (which jives with the observation that the approximation worsens with the length of the list), but of course, this is very fast to compute.